# STM32 Some Beginner Questions

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32f10x

I want to start working with ARM micro controllers especially STM32 family. So please give me some resource for learning everything needed step by step. I've searched a lot but I found no clear results for beginners. Many of examples on the web are for STM32 Discovery Boards but I need to design a PCB from scratch (this isn't my problem) and use one STM32 Micro controller + USB connector + ... on my own board.
So first of all I need a free IDE and compiler (without limitation in size of code, etc) then how to download hex code to a STM32 with my own board not discovery boards.
Also I'm going to use STM32F103x8 that has USB-2 communication interface itself.

Comment: You forgot the moon and the stick it goes on.

Answer (score 2):

The options I am aware of:

1. ST-Nucleo or ST-Nucleo-32. These are mbed boards, with a free browser
   based IDE at mbed.org. They have a hardware ST-Link on board, like a
   Discovery board. However, program upload is even simpler. An mbed
   looks like a USB flash drive to a host PC, so when you copy the
   program binary to it, it's uploaded. The boards are about $12 or
   less.
2. LeafLabs Maple (see http://forums.leaflabs.com/). LeafLabs no longer
   sell them, but they can be bought from eBay, Aliexpress, etc. The
   Maple IDE is still available.
3. [stm32duino](http://www.stm32duino.com/), who have forked LeafLabs Maple library and
   bootloader, and integrated the toolchain into the Arduino
   environment. So it programs using the Arduino IDE.

I would **STRONGLY** recommend using a ready built development board to get started. You could waste weeks making your own board, and getting it debugged.

You will likely, eventually, want to get a hardware debugger. STM32-mbed and Discovery have those built in, ST-Link-V2, in such a way that they can be used on external boards. So you get a development board, with a hardware debugger, for less than he cost of a hardware debugger alone.

A ready made Development board will give you a way to compare results from your new (possibly buggy?) board to something which has been debugged and is stable. This will save a lot of time and effort.
If you search around, you will find that [embedded GCC for ARM](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) is available, and you could use that from the command line, or integrate into NetBeans or Eclipse.

There is a free Windows upload program which will work with ST-Link on the ST site. There is a reverse-engineered, open source upload program which runs on Linucx and Mac OS X on github, [Texane/stlink](https://github.com/texane/stlink)

Their are quite active communities at mbed and stm32duino. Mbed is interested in many processors, the stm32duino community is focused on STM32.

There are many sets of CAD for Open Source DIY PCB's, for example mine are at [github/gbulmer](https://github.com/gbulmer/openstm32hw/tree/master/Orone-mini-v0).